# Setting the connection timeout in Virtuoso server via connection string

Tags: connection, timeout, virtuoso

I started the Virtuoso service on Windows with the following configurations (this is the important part of the config file):

```
ResultSetMaxRows            = 10000
MaxQueryCostEstimationTime  = 40000 ; in seconds
MaxQueryExecutionTime       = 60000 ; in seconds
DefaultQuery                = select * where{?x ?y ?z}
DeferInferenceRulesInit     = 0  ; controls inference rules loading
```

I'm using the `dotNetRDF` library to make local queries to the local server. The library makes the timeout 30seconds, but I can override the default timeout by sending a connection string when starting the object:

```
VirtuosoManager manager = new VirtuosoManager("Server=localhost;Uid=dba;pwd=dba;Connection Timeout=500");
```

It still times out at 30seconds, if my query is complex enough to process in more than 30 seconds...

My project uses some complex queries, so I need the timeout property as large as possible. How can I override that property ?

Comment: Also asked, and answered, at [Answers.SemanticWeb.Com](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/14568/overriding-dotnetrdfdatavirtuoso-timeout-property).

Also asked at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321797/setting-the-connection-timeout-in-virtuoso-server-via-connection-string).

Answer (score 1):

The Virtuoso ADO.Net Provider DBcommand class has a [CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand_properties.aspx) property, with a default value of 30 seconds, as detailed in the [VirtuosoCommand class documentation](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/virtclientref.html#vcrvirtuosocommandclass).

This is the timeout you are hitting (not a Connection Timeout).

As of revision 2148, the dotNetRDF library allows this property value to be set as required.